# Place a div next to a child div

Tags: html, css

i have a simple question.

My code:

'''

```
<div class="container"> 
      <div class="child_1"> 
      </div> 
      <div class="child_2"> 
      </div> 
 </div> 

 <div class="another_div"> 
 </div>
```

'''

How to place 'another_div' next to 'child_2' ?

[image]

Comment: can you post your css? please read [mcve]

Comment: do you not have access to the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap all your content in a new `<div>` with a class `main-container` (say).

Now, set the display of the main container to flex;

```
display: flex;
```

As another `<div>` is supposed to be added to the left of the elements of the `<div>` with class `container`, we set the flex-direction to row-reverse.

```
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

The entire main container gets aligned to the right. As it's already in reverse, we set justify-content to flex-end.

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```

The `another_div` is added at the bottom and not on the top, which implies the items are vertically aligned to the bottom. For this, we align the items to the flex-end.

```
align-items: flex-end;
```

---

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

> Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/geekyquentin/pen/wvyJOBX

Answer (score -1):

```css
.child_1,
.child_2,
.another_div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child_1,
.child_2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.another_div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  order: 1;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child_1"> </div>
  <div class="child_2"> </div>
</div>

<div class="another_div"></div>
```